# Save selected column data from csv file using tkinter

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I have a csv file with 2 columns, Using tkinter I am displaying the .csv file and then I am selecting the particular row which I want, but the thing is I want to store only the column data of selected row for example if I am selecting row 1 I need to store the data of column 2 row 1 in a variable.
Please help me out to achieve this
Below i the csv file

```
    info,Id 
    ABC,123 
    CDE,456 
    EFG,789
```

Below is my python code

```
import csv
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb



def item_selected(event):
    for selected_item in tree.selection():
        item = tree.item(selected_item)
        record = item['values']
        print(record)
        # show a message
         showinfo(title='You have selected below', message=','.join(record))
        if answer:
            mb.showinfo(title='Progress', message='Thanks for selecting')
        else:

            mb.showinfo(title='Return Back', message='Please try again')
            root.destroy()


root = Tk()
root.title("info and ID")
width = 500
height = 400
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width / 2) - (width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (height / 2)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
root.resizable(0, 0)

TableMargin = Frame(root, width=500)
TableMargin.pack(side=TOP)
scrollbarx = Scrollbar(TableMargin, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scrollbary = Scrollbar(TableMargin, orient=VERTICAL)
tree = ttk.Treeview(TableMargin, columns=("info", "Id"), height=400, selectmode="extended",
                    yscrollcommand=scrollbary.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbarx.set)
scrollbary.config(command=tree.yview)
scrollbary.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbarx.config(command=tree.xview)
scrollbarx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
tree.heading('info', text="info", anchor=W)
tree.heading('Id', text="Id", anchor=W)
tree.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
tree.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=200)
tree.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=200)
tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', item_selected)
tree.pack()

with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        info = row['info']
        Id = row['Id']
        tree.insert("", 0, values=(info, Id))
# Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

The expected result is when i print variable record it should print the Only the ID
Example for selecting row 1 the variable should contain only 123
What I am observing is ['ABC', '123']
It should eliminate ['ABC'] and print only 123.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tree.set()` instead of `tree.item()`:

```py
def item_selected(event):
    record = tree.set(tree.selection(), 'Id')
    print(record)
    ...
```